# Angularjs ui-grid: How to group column by year, month, week?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In the example below, I have a column of date data called "Mix Date". I can group them but it can only be grouped by day. What if I want to group it by month in order to see how many rows are there in each month? Or Year, week?

[See this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0QzED6iOUJrZ3nrcRGB?p=preview).

I only used the basic setting of grid-grouping:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-grouping></div>
```

Note that I am using ui-grid, not ng-grid.

Comment: Tong, were you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: nope...found nothing about this..